# Переключение активных элементов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть список из шести элементов, как сделать так , чтобы допустим , я нажал на 5-тый блок , active_el присвоилось 5 , а при помощи v-if который установлен на блок , отобразился только 5-тый блок, если я нажму допустим на второй элемент , пятый скроется , а отобразиться второй ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
     return {
        active_el: 0,
        headerItems: [
           {id: 0, text: 'Один'},
           {id: 1, text: 'Два'},
           {id: 2, text: 'Три'},
           {id: 3, text: 'Четыре'},
           {id: 4, text: 'Пять'},
           {id: 5, text: 'Шесть'},
        ],
      }
  },
  methods: {
    activate (el){
        this.active_el = el;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.header__list {
   display: flex;
   width: 1311px;
   height: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 30px;
   left: calc(50% - 350px/2);
}
.header__item {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
         <ul class="header__list">
            <li class="header__item" 
            v-for="(headerItem, item) in headerItems"
            :key="item.id"
            @click="activate(item.id - 1)">
               <p :class="headerItem.class">{{headerItem.text}}</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="pervii" v-if="active_el === 0">Привет 0</div>
         <div class="vtoroi" v-if="active_el === 1">Привет 1</div>
         <div class="tretii" v-if="active_el === 2">Привет 2</div>
         <div class="tretii" v-if="active_el === 3">Привет 3</div>
         <div class="tretii" v-if="active_el === 4">Привет 4</div>
         <div class="tretii" v-if="active_el === 5">Привет 5</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну проблема в том, что в `item` нет id. Так как это индекс массива. Смотрите внимательно что вы в `v-for` по написали. Так же откуда взялся `headerItem.class`? которого в принципе нигде не объявлено

Столько `v-if` нельзя делать. Не дублируйте код!! Ниже пример как сделать чуть по другому

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
     return {
        active_el: null,
        headerItems: [
           {id: 0, text: 'Один'},
           {id: 1, text: 'Два'},
           {id: 2, text: 'Три'},
           {id: 3, text: 'Четыре'},
           {id: 4, text: 'Пять'},
           {id: 5, text: 'Шесть'},
        ],
      }
  },
  
  created() {
    this.active_el = this.headerItems[0];
  },
  
  methods: {
    activate (el){
        this.active_el = el;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.header__list {
   display: flex;
   width: 1311px;
   height: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 30px;
   left: calc(50% - 350px/2);
}
.header__item {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
         <ul class="header__list">
            <li class="header__item" 
            v-for="headerItem in headerItems"
            :key="headerItem.id"
            @click="activate(headerItem)">
               <p :class="headerItem.class">{{headerItem.text}}</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="pervii" v-if="active_el">{{active_el.text}}</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: А если у меня допустим будет не просто слова выводиться , а будут меняться вся страница , до этого верхнего меню ?

Comment: @Young ну просто `<my-component :item="active_el"  v-if="active_el" />` Где компонент будет новым шаблоном тела документа. Если надо разные подключать, то то же не надо 5 разных строк дублировать. Делаете встроенный компонент vue. `<component :is="active_el.nameComponent" :item="active_el" />`